# Jquery on change event is not firing when selecting the same drop down option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a drop down like this and I have a textarea field . I want when ever uses a option from the dropdown the dropdown selected value will append in the text area field  and I have used change event for the dropdown but the problem with it is that when I am selecting the same value again then the change event is not firing. I have searched and many people suggest to use click event of dropdown but when I am using the click event then the test I am selecting is appearing two times but I want only the selected text of the dropdown to be appear.My JS code is like this.

```
<select class="form-control" id="drpLinkType">
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Post</option>
    <option value="2">Pre</option>
    <option value="2">Test</option>
</select>

$('#drpLinkType').click(function () {
    debugger;

    var $txt = $("#txt");
    var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
    var txtToAdd = $('#drpLinkType :selected').text();
    $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));

})
```

[jsfiddle.net/w0c9o7ox](https://jsfiddle.net/w0c9o7ox/) create the js fiddle. Here you can see that if I click the same option for then it is not working

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: can you create a working jsfiddle

Comment: Maybe use `.change()` instead of `.click()`: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w0c9o7ox/     create the js fiddle. Here you can see that if I click the same option for then it is not working

Answer (score 2):

Set `.value` of `<select>` to empty string `""` using `this.value = ""` or `$(this).val("")` at last line of `change` event, else if same `<option>` is selected in succession the `.value` has not changed.

You can also include `<label>` element with `for` attribute set to `<select>` `.id` value to set current `.textContent` of selected `<option>`.

```js
$('#drpLinkType').on('change', function () {
        //debugger;
        var $txt = $("#txt");
        var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
        var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
        var txtToAdd = $('#drpLinkType :selected').text();
        $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
        this.labels[0].innerHTML = this.selectedOptions[0].textContent;
        $('#drpLinkType').val("");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="drpLinkType">
        <option value="0">Please select a option</option>
        <option value="2">Post</option>
        <option value="2">Pre</option>
        <option value="2">Test</option>
    </select><label for="drpLinkType"></label>
    <textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70" placeholder="Enter text ..." ></textarea>
```

Comment: but if I do like this then user will not able to see which dropdown option they have selected

Comment: I just wonder what you could have done to be on the penalty box.

Answer (score 0):

Use click even instead. Like so (I moved the appending of the text into a separate function for clarity):

```js
$('#drpLinkType').on('click', function (event) {
  var text = $('#drpLinkType :selected').text();
  appendText(text);
});

function appendText(text) {
  var $txt = $('#txt');
  var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
  var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
  $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + text + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select class="form-control" id="drpLinkType">
        <option value="0">Please select a option</option>
        <option value="2" >Post</option>
        <option value="2">Pre</option>
        <option value="2">Test</option>
    </select>
    <textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70" placeholder="Enter text ..." ></textarea>
```

But, if you have control over the HTML, this would be optimal:

```js
$('#drpLinkType').on('click', function (event) {
  appendText(event.target.value);
});

function appendText(text) {
  var $txt = $('#txt');
  var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
  var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
  $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + text + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="drpLinkType">
        <option value="">Please select a option</option>
        <option value="Post" >Post</option>
        <option value="Pre">Pre</option>
        <option value="Test">Test</option>
    </select>
  <textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70" placeholder="Enter text ..." ></textarea>
```

Comment: yes with click one problem will solve but if you run the code and test you will see that the selected text is adding two times.

Comment: @Utpal i think i don't understand. so the goal is to select two times the same options, not append the same text again, but fire the change event?

Comment: Yes you can say that

Comment: any more suggestion please

Comment: @Utpal sure, let me ask you first, do you have control over the HTML?